Question About Absolute Continuity of A Finite Signed Measure (Proof of Proposition 4.4.5 in Measure Theory by Donald Cohn)
I am self-studying measure theory using Measure Theory by Donald Cohn. I got stuck on a step in his proof of Proposition 4.4.5. Here is the statement of the proposition:

Proposition 4.4.5$\quad$ Let $\mu$ be a finite signed measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, and let $F_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $F_{\mu}(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$. Then $F_{\mu}$ is absolutely continuous if and only if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Here is the step of the proof on which I got stuck:

Proof$\quad$ $\dots$ Now suppose that $F_{\mu}$ is absolutely continuous. Then $V_{F_{\mu}}$ is absolutely continuous (Lemma 4.4.4), and so the functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ defined by $F_1=\frac{V_{F_{\mu}}+F_{\mu}}{2}$ and $F_2=\frac{V_{F_{\mu}}-F_{\mu}}{2}$ are absolutely continuous. Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be the finite positive measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ that correspond to $F_1$ and $F_2$. $\dots$

I don't understand why there is are finite positive measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ that correspond to $F_1$ and $F_2$. So far what I can think of is the following:
Since $F_{\mu}$ vanishes at $-\infty$ and is right-continuous, $V_{F_{\mu}}$ vanishes at $-\infty$ and is right-continuous, and thus $F_1$ amd $F_2$ both vanish at $-\infty$ and are right-continuous. Then there are finite signed  measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ that correspond to $F_1$ and $F_2$ (Proposition 4.4.3).
Could someone please help me explain why $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ must also be positive measures? Thanks a lot in advance!

Related Definitions and Results:

Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $[a,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    a \leq t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F[a,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $[a,b]$} is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F[a,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $[a,b]$ if $V_F[a,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $(-\infty,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $(-\infty,b]$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^{n}\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $(-\infty,b]$ if $V_F(-\infty,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n < +\infty.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$, the variation of $F$ over $\mathbb{R}$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,+\infty) = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{t=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) if $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$ is finite. If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, then the variation of $F$ is the function $V_F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $V_F(x)=V_F(-\infty,x]$.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Define a function $F_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting
\begin{align}
    F_{\mu}(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])\tag1
\end{align}
hold at each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers, then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=1}^n|F_{\mu}(t_i)-F_{\mu}(t_{i-1})| = \sum_{i=1}^n|\mu((t_{i-1},t_i])| \leq |\mu|(\mathbb{R});
\end{align*}
it follows that $V_{F_{\mu}}(-\infty,+\infty)\leq|\mu|(\mathbb{R})$ and hence that $F_{\mu}$ is of finite variation.


Proposition$\quad$ The function $F_{\mu}$ defined by (1) vanishes at $-\infty$ and is right-continuous..


Proposition$\quad$ Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation. If $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$, then
\begin{align}
    V_F(-\infty,b] = V_F(-\infty,a]+V_F[a,b].
\end{align}


Lemma 4.4.1$\quad$ Let $F$ be a function of finite variation on $\mathbb{R}$. Then

$V_F$ is bounded and nondecreasing,
$V_F$ vanishes at $-\infty$, and
if $F$ is right-continuous, then $V_F$ is right-continuous.



Proposition 4.4.2$\quad$ Let $F$ be a function of finite variation on $\mathbb{R}$. Then there are bounded nondecreasing functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ such that $F=F_1-F_2$. (The functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ by $F_1=\frac{V_F+F}{2}$ and $F_2=\frac{V_F-F}{2}$ have the required properties.)


Proposition 4.4.3$\quad$ Equation (1) defines a bijection $\mu\mapsto F_{\mu}$ between the set of all finite signed measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and the set of all right-continuous functions of finite variation that vanish at $-\infty$.


Lemma 4.4.4$\quad$ If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous and of finite variation, then $V_F$ is absolutely continuous.


We need to prove that $\mu_1(A)\geq0$ and $\mu_2(A)\geq0$ for $\forall A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Is sufficient to prove that  $\mu_1([a,b])\geq0$ and $\mu_2([a,b])\geq0$ for $b>a$ $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
Note that:$$
\mu_1([a,b])=F_1(b)-F_1(a)=\frac{V_{F_{\mu}}(b)+F_{\mu}(b)-V_{F_{\mu}}(a)-F_{\mu}(a)}{2}\\
\mu_2([a,b])=F_2(b)-F_2(a)=\frac{V_{F_{\mu}}(b)-F_{\mu}(b)-V_{F_{\mu}}(a)+F_{\mu}(a)}{2}\\
$$
So its enough to prove that:$$
V_{F_{\mu}}(b)\geq ∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+V_{F_{\mu}}(a)
$$
If $t<a$ and $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ is a finite sequence such that
$$
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq t.
$$
then
$$
 V_F(b) \geq ∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+∣F_{\mu}(a)-F_{\mu}(t_n)∣+ \\ \sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})| \\ \geq ∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+ \sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|
$$
so
$$
 V_F(b) \geq ∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+V_F(t) \quad \forall t<a
$$
$V_F$ is right-continuous so taking the limit $\lim_{t  \to a^+}$ in both sides, we have:
$$
 V_F(b) \geq ∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+\lim_{t  \to a^+}V_F(t)=\\
∣F_{\mu}(b)-F_{\mu}(a)∣+V_F(a)
$$
Edit
I will demonstrate the proposition using the propositions given in the book.
With the demonstration above, I also showed that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are non-decreasing. Therefore, both are bounded, non-decreasing, and right-continuous. Using Proposition 1.3.8, there exist positive measures $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ such that $F_1(x) = \nu_1((-\infty, x])$ and $F_2(x) = \nu_2((-\infty, x])$. These measures have the characteristics of the measures in Proposition 4.4.3, and by their uniqueness, we have $\nu_1 = \mu_1$ and $\nu_2 = \mu_2$.

Why is it sufficient to prove that $\mu_1([a,b])\geq0$ and $\mu_2([a,b])\geq0$ for $b>a$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

@Beerus See the edit, please.

Thank you so much!
